# Only keep a limited amount of elements per key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

at the moment i try to find a solution for the following problem:

After some processing, i try limiting the amount of values in my key-value RDD for a key to a certain number (for example 200).

My initial solution was to do a *groupByKey*, to get all elements with the same key into one partition, followed by a *flatMapValues* where i would just take the first 200 elements of the iterable.

Although this solution works perfectly fine for smaller data, it seems to be really inefficient and does not work when i want to process bigger data.

Someone has an idea how this can be pulled off more efficiently ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If data is dense enough (number of values per key is >> n, where n is the number of records to retain) you can optimize this:

- Take at most n elements per key from each partition.
- Shuffle.
- Combine until you have n elements per key and ignore the rest.

In the worst case scenario this will shuffle 200 * number-of-partitions * number-of-keys.

This can be implemented with `combineByKey` or `aggregateByKey`. With pseudocode (you should use mutable collections to improve performance, it is also possible to improve `mergeCombiners` to avoid copying if the first buffer has already enough records):

```
val rdd: RDD[(K, V)]
rdd.combineByKey(
  x => Vector(x),
  (acc: Vector[V], x: V) => if (acc.length < n) acc :+ x else acc, 
  (acc1: Vector[V], acc2: Vector[V]) => (acc1 ++ acc2) take n
)
```